# getting an error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'drop' where is my mistake?

Tags: python

**Here is my code that i have written to make a model for ML**

```
import pandas  as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", sep=";")

data = [["G1", "G2", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences"]]

predict = "G3"

X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
y = np.array(data[predict])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1)

linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()

linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)
print(acc)



linear.fit(x_train, y_train)
acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)
print(acc)
```

**This is the Error I am getting:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/WORK/Desktop/ML_AI/Projects/ML_AI1/Regression Working File.py", line 13, in <module>
    X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'drop'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Where have I gone wrong , what should I change?**

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
X = np.array(data.drop([predict], 1))
```

into

```
X = np.array(data.drop(columns=[predict], 1))
```

[pd.DataFrame.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) tries to drop an index called "G3" instead of a column if you do not specify the axis.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete "predict" to estimate? 
This is the answer to drop "predict". You should use "remove" to drop value of "predict".

```
data = ["G1", "G2", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences"]
predict = "G3"
data.remove(predict)
    
X = np.array(data)
```

When you run this code, you can get the values below.

```
['G1', 'G2', 'studytime', 'failures', 'absences']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot I just tweaked this

```
data = [["G1", "G2", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences"]]
```

To this:

```
data = data[["G1", "G2", "G3", "studytime", "failures", "absences"]]
```

*This solved my problem, and thanks for the replies*